# Extract multiple result set using interface projection in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Currently I am able to use projection interface on native stored procedure call which returns single Result set. Sample code below.

```
// Projection interface
public interface CustomUserRs {
    String getUserId();
    String getUserName();
    Integer getUserAge();
}
```

```
@Query(value = "CALL getUserList(:userAge)", nativeQuery = true)
List<CustomUserRs> getUserList(@Param("userAge") Integer userAge);
```

Above code works fine and returns me list of user where the age criteria matches.
Now I have another stored procedure which returns me both list of users in one result set, and List of devices in another result set.

```
// Projection interface
public interface DeviceListRs {
   String getUserId();
   String getDeviceId();
   String getDeviceName();
   double getDeviceCost();
}
```

```
@Query(value = "CALL getUserAndDeviceList(:userAge)", nativeQuery = true)
//I want this stored procedure call to map 1st result set to CustomUserRs
//and 2nd result set to DeviceListRs
List<CustomUserRs> getUserAndDeviceList(@Param("userAge") Integer userAge);
```

I want to fetch both the result set using interface projection itself.